# How to stop circle click on Button while showing Menu in ExtReact;

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, extreact

So, I have a problem with a click on Button while showing/hiding menu and menu items, because it performs a click with a circle around it (i.e. a circle click). How to stop that in ExtReact? Which property of a component to use or which css property in ExtReact to use to stop that?

So, on the first picture you will see a button:

[image]

And on the second button you will see a on click operation:

[image]

How to stop on circle click on the second picture?

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to use the property `ripple` and to set it to `false` on the specific button.